# Counting number of '1s' in a byte

Tags: c, embedded, microcontroller, conditional-statements, memory-efficient

Test Environment:
Hardware: Microcontroller

Language: C

Compiler: IAR, HEW, MPLAB, Keil...

We have a test variable

```
uint8_t unTestVar;  // uint8_t is type def to unsigned char (8-bit)
```

If in the program flow some value is moved in this unTestVar, how can we **efficiently** count the numbers of 1s in it.

Suppose

```
unTestVar = 0xA0;  // unTestVar is 10100000 in binary
```

so there are two 1s in this.
Similarly for,

```
unTestVar = 89;    // unTestVar is 10000110 in binary
```

here we have three 1s.

Yes there are many approaches to count the number of 1s but which approach is efficient (less processing and memory usage). Note that I am in a very limited resource environment.

Comment: use [__builtin_popcount()](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html) if using gcc or if available.

Comment: Keep doing `(unTestVar & (unTestVar - 1))` unless `unTestVar` reduces to `0`. If you do not know why this works,  find out yourself...

Comment: You should look at the dozens of existing questions and web-pages that already cover this topic, and then decide which of the several option makes the most sense given the constraints that only *you* know about.

Comment: I've marked it as a duplicate of a C++ question, but all the answers are non-C++-specific.  Use the search facility to find other duplicates.

Comment: As @OliCharlesworth stated, it has been widely answered. I'll just add this link though : http://gurmeet.net/puzzles/fast-bit-counting-routines/

Answer (score 1):

```
const uint8_t m1 = 0x55;
const uint8_t m2 = 0x33;
const uint8_t m3 = 0x0F;
a = (a & m1) + ((a >> 1) & m1);
a = (a & m2) + ((a >> 2) & m2);
a = (a & m3) + ((a >> 4) & m3);
```

After this a contains the answer. If you don't want to loose a, use some temp variable of type uint_8.

**Explanation**
Adding two bits would always fit in 2 bits. (00, 01 or 10). Using m1, all bits at even places (considering 0 as even and starting count from 0) are added with bits at odd places. (Shifting down by 1 place and using mask)

`a = (a & m1) + ((a >> 1) & m1);`

```
       +--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
a      |b7|b6|b5|b4|b3|b2|b1|b0|
       +--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+

       +--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
m1     | 0| 1|| 0| 1| 0| 1| 0| 1
       +--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+

       +--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
a & m1 | 0|b6| 0|b4| 0|b2| 0|b0|
       +--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+

       +--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
a>>1   | 0|b7|b6|b5|b4|b3|b2|b1|
       +--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+

       +--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
a>>1&m1| 0|b7| 0|b5| 0|b3| 0|b1|
       +--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+

Adding (a&m1) and (a >> 1) & m1 and assigning to a
       +--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
a      |b7+b6|b5+b4|b3+b2|b1+b0|
       +--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
```

Similarly going ahead for next step `a = (a & m2) + ((a >> 2) & m2);`

```
           +--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
    m2     | 0| 0| 1| 1| 0| 0| 1| 1|
           +--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+

           +--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
  a >> 2   |  0  |b7+b6|b5+b4|b3+b2|
           +--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+

           +--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
    a&m2   |  0  |b5+b4|  0  |b1+b0|
           +--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+

           +--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
 a>>2&m2   |  0  |b7+b6|  0  |b3+b2|
           +--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+

Adding (a&m2) and (a >> 2) & m2 and assigining to a
           +--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
     a     |b7+b6+b5+b4|b3+b2+b1+b0|
           +--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
```

Third step `a = (a & m3) + ((a >> 4) & m3);`

```
           +--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
    m3     | 0| 0| 0| 0| 1| 1| 1| 1|
           +--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+

           +--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
  a >> 4   |  0  |  0  |b7+b6|b5+b4|
           +--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+

           +--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
    a&m3   |  0  |  0  |b3+b2|b1+b0|
           +--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+

           +--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
 a>>4&m3   |  0  |  0  |b7+b6|b5+b4|
           +--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+

Adding (a&m2) and (a >> 2) & m2 and assigining to a
           +--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
     a     |b7+b6+b5+b4+b3+b2+b1+b0|
           +--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
```

So finally a contains the sum of all bits. `0` bits don't contribute in the sum so it actually contains the count of set bits.

Comment: Can you explain how this works? I don't think this will produce the correct results the way it's written.

Comment: @Groo Explanation added. Thank for the comment, it helped me catching a typo.